# Customize text area field in yii2

Tags: textarea, yii2, active-form

I am using Yii2 active form. I want to customize my text area field. For example, I want to add bold, italic, underline and add attachments etc. options in my text area field. How can this be done in yii2?

**My form field:**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textArea(['rows' => '6']) ?>
```

I want to make the textarea look like this screen shot below.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply use one of the solutions out there? [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) is pretty awesome.

Comment: yes, this will definitely work. but i want to make options custom without using any editor

Comment: Ok. thank you @Blizz I have used this editor and it worked fine https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget